# Why does .getElementById in VBA return error 462?

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

The following VBA code returns

> Run-time error '462' The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

citing the line `.getElementById("txt"name").Value = "Arun Banik"`.

This code is from [here](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/web-scrapping-fill-a-web-form-from-excel-using-vba.htm) but I have a similar objective.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const sSiteName = "https://www.encodedna.com/css-tutorials/form/contact-form.htm"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ' Open Internet Explorer Browser and keep it visible.
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate sSiteName
    End With
    
    While oIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    Set oHDoc = oIE.Document
    
    With oHDoc
        .getElementById("txtName").Value = "Arun Banik"
        .getElementById("txtAge").Value = "35"
        .getElementById("txtEmail").Value = "arun@hotmail.com"
        .getElementById("selCountry").Value = "India"   ' Assign value to the dropdown list in the web form.
        .getElementById("msg").Value = "Hi, I am Arun Banik and this is a test message. :-)"
        
        .getElementById("bt").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's isn't too much wrong with the code you posted. What I think is happening is the code isn't detecting it's starting to load in the `While` loop. So I added a small delay to try and resolve this. Also, I didn't see a need for the document variable, so I removed it. This code is working for me.

```
Option Explicit
Const sSiteName = "https://www.encodedna.com/css-tutorials/form/contact-form.htm"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oIE As Object
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ' Open Internet Explorer Browser and keep it visible.
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate sSiteName
    End With
    
    'Wait a few seconds for the page to load
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
    While oIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    With oIE.Document
        .getElementById("txtName").Value = "Arun Banik"
        .getElementById("txtAge").Value = "35"
        .getElementById("txtEmail").Value = "arun@hotmail.com"
        .getElementById("selCountry").Value = "India"
        .getElementById("msg").Value = "Hi, I am Arun Banik and this is a test message. :-)"
        .getElementById("bt").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great. Feel feel to vote/mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you do not have the proper references set.

Add "Microsoft Internet Control" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library" to your list of references (Alt + F11 > Tools > References...)

Comment: This is unlikely to be the case. If they didn't have the reference, they would get "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" on the line `Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument`.